# Google Account in Android App

Tags: android

I'm creating an application in Android that would provide several login choices such as Facebook and Twitter. Now, I would like to ask if there's a way to provide a custom login page for Google account? If it's possible, how? Do you have any sample code to help me start with this? Thanks.

Comment: [Refer This](http://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator-for-android/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't make Custom Login pages for Facebook ,Twitter or google there are lots of Api for Facebook , Twitter and Google plus , you can use this Library or jar file like

```
 1) for Twitter you can use
```

http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html this jar file

```
 2) for Facebook use this
```

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/f/Downloadfacebookandroidsdkjar.htm
      or http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/385/

```
3) for google plus use this site
```

https://developers.google.com/+/api/

https://developers.google.com/+/downloads/

Comment: edit my answer for google plus :) is my answer usefull for u ?

Answer (score 0):

You can start reading from [Google Android Docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android#account)

Sample codes are already there.